# Does LINQ Query Execution varies from one machine to another machine

Tags: c#, linq

I am doing one sample that fetches data from DB

lets called the result from DB as Students.

Now I am using LINQ query to fetch results from Students object.

```
var studetails = Students.Select( new
{
ID = student.Id;
Name = student.Name;
FullName = Student.FirstName +" "+ Student.LastName;
}).ToList();
```

I am seeing the execution time for this query is varying from one machine to another machine.

Suppose if there are 1500 students then in one machine it is taking 30 sec, but in another machine it is taking nearly 2-3 minutes.

Could some one please suggest me.

Thanks,
Chandu.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, it depends on machine power (CPU, RAM...).

In the other hand, there's another point: what if the database doesn't configure right indexes in order to optimize the whole query?

I doubt the same query would generate different SQL under the hoods. It should be a machine power and/or database design differences between both deploys.

Answer (score 0):

Your question requires more facts in order for it to be answered.

Does the running code and the database live in the same machine?  You are unclear on this point.  What does the term "another machine" refer to, the database or the machine running the LINQ query.
You have to specify what your architecture is?
Is the code being run under a web server?
Is it a console app?
What is the topology/status of your network?

When you answer these, then you can conclude whether anything can be done about it.